# Closed subspace with distant one from $w$

Tags: normed-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a normed space and $x$ is a unit vector in X.

We wanted to show that there is a closed subspace $E$ such that $d(x,W)=1$ and $$X=E\oplus\{\lambda x:\lambda\in\mathbb{F}\}.$$

Any hint please

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose you meant $d(x,E)=1$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242443/dw-v-1-and-u-v-oplus-lambda-w-lambda-in-mathbbf